# What determines whether the reputation amount on my profile's Reputation tab is green or white?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

On my [User Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756409/tylerh?tab=summary) page, within the Summary tab, a Reputation section is shown, listing the four most recent posts (all answers) of mine that have been voted up/down. Three of these posts have a reputation amount listed in a box with a green background. At first I thought that meant the answer was accepted. But the fourth entry (the most recent one), shows a reputation box with a white background... the problem there being that I know this answer is accepted, too.

[image]

What determines whether that box is white or green?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost correct. The Reputation section of the Summary tab shows **Recent** reputation activity. If you notice from the reputation amount, and [your own reputation audit trail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756409/tylerh?tab=reputation), you'll see that you specifically *gained reputation from that answer being accepted* recently. That is what the green reputation box indicates.

The Microsoft Edge answer is accepted, but wasn't accepted recently. You gained +10 reputation from an upvote on an answer that was accepted long ago. Only reputation gained recently via acceptance of one of your answers will cause that reputation box to turn green.